# What does the jquery selector '$("#someID > * *")' mean?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the meaning of this selector: `$("#someID > * *")`

I know that `>` means child nodes and `*` means all nodes, but I'm confused by the two asterisks.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It selects all grandchildren or lower of `#someID`.

### Explanation:

`#someID > *` [selects all *direct* children](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) of `#someID`.
Adding  `*` will [select all descendants](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) of those children.  (but not the children themselves)

Thus, it will select all descendants of `#someID` except for its direct children.

It could also be written as `$('#someID *').not('#someID > *')`.

Comment: Could also be written as: `$('#someID').children().find('*');`

Comment: @Patrick: You're right; that's much clearer, and probably a little faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#someID > * *')
```

Get all/any elements which are ***direct/immediate*** children of `#someID` and then get any ***descendants*** inside those elements there by only getting ***descendants***.

Comment: Nope. It won't select its direct children.

Comment: @Harmen: I did not say either, it will select descendants ultimately :)

Comment: @Harmen: Yes that could have caused the confusion, added few more words at the end. Thanks :)